# Update float data type field with blank spaces in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

A blank space will be treated as 0 if using float:

for eg:

```
declare @f float
set @f = '' 
print @f
```

I tried using blank spaces in the columns using update statement, the output will be 0.
But i want to save blank space and retrieve blackspace for field value.
How to possible this.

I am using to update table value from xml file,i am getting balnk value from xml file,but i save this,it will be saved like zero,but i wnat to save this as blank

I need to allow blank space for an decimal parameter how can we do that ?

Comment: As I understand your problem, you want to insert blank space in a float column, which is not possible. You can't insert non-numeric data except `null` in numeric columns.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store a blank like you require in a `float` column, you need to make it nullable and save `null` value into this column.

Empty string (`''`) can only be saved into `varchar`, `text` and similar text columns.